# como remover vírgulas desnecessárias usando sed no shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Estou tentando criar um script para automatizar um trabalho que faço. Estava tudo indo bem, até encontrar esse problema. Quando uso o `sed`, para remover uma palavra da string, a saída mostra 2 vírgulas juntas, e isso pode causar falhas no parâmetro editado. Ex: Removendo "BBBBB"

domain.vmfull="AAAAA,BBBBB,CCCCC,ABCDE"

domain.vmfull="AAAAA,,CCCCC,ABCDE"

Pergunta 1 Como posso remover uma dessas 2 vírgulas? A saída deve ser assim:

domain.vmfull="AAAAA,CCCCC,ABCDE"

Questão 2 De outra forma, quando a palavra a ser removida for a última ou a primeira da lista, a vírgula desnecessária será a primeira ou a última. Como posso evitar as duas possibilidades? Ex: como abaixo removendo AAAAA:

domain.vmfull=",BBBBB,CCCCC,ABCDE"

a saída deve ser:

domain.vmfull="BBBBB,CCCCC,ABCDE"

```
bash-3.2$ echo "$options_sched"
"-vmfulltype=vstor -vmbackuptype=fullvm -asnodename=NODE1 -MODE=IFIncremental -domain.vmfull="AAAAA,BBBBB,CCCCC,ABCDE""

bash-3.2$ options_final=$(echo $options_sched | sed "s#BBBBB##gI")

bash-3.2$ echo $options_final
"-vmfulltype=vstor -vmbackuptype=fullvm -asnodename=NODE1 -MODE=IFIncremental -domain.vmfull="AAAAA,,CCCCC,ABCDE"" 



#Question - 2
bash-3.2$ echo "$options_sched"
"-vmfulltype=vstor -vmbackuptype=fullvm -asnodename=NODE1 -MODE=IFIncremental -domain.vmfull="AAAAA,BBBBB,CCCCC,ABCDE""

bash-3.2$ options_final=$(echo $options_sched | sed "s#AAAAA##gI")

bash-3.2$ echo $options_final
"-vmfulltype=vstor -vmbackuptype=fullvm -asnodename=NODE1 -MODE=IFIncremental -domain.vmfull=",BBBBB,CCCCC,ABCDE""
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a forma mais correta de resolver esse problema é escrever um script que *interpreta* o texto, compreende e divide as partes que interessam para você para assim manusear com maior facilidade. (Por exemplo procurar o parâmetro `domain.vmfull`, dividir o conteúdo passado nele pelas vírgulas, remover o ítem desejado e fazer um join de volta. Isso pode ser feito tranquilamente em um script bash ou em python.)

Tentar realizar esse tipo de processamento de texto mais complexo usando apenas `sed` pode acabar sendo um tiro no pé.

Como sua pergunta pede usando `sed`, uma opção não muito elegante, mas fácil de entender seria concatenar múltiplos `sed`'s em cascata:

Por exemplo:

- Questão 1: você pode substituir ",," por "," (Duas vírgulas por uma):

```
$  echo $A | sed 's/BBBBB//g' | sed 's/,,/,/g'
-vmfulltype=vstor -vmbackuptype=fullvm -asnodename=NODE1 -MODE=IFIncremental -domain.vmfull="AAAAA,CCCCC,ABCDE"
```

Claro, você precisa ter certeza que fora desse intervalo você não tem em algum outro lugar "duas vírgulas seguidas" que realmente precisavam ser duas vírgulas seguidas, pois elas também vão ser substituídas. Poderia pensar também em uma expressão regular (regex) mais complexa, porém isso iria precisar de uma análise e uma garantia muito forte de que o texto segue um molde específico.

- Questão 2: Você pode substituir `vmfull=",` por `vmfull="` , e substituir `,"` no final da frase por `"`. Abaixo, `$`(símbolo de cifrão) representa o final da frase:

```
$ echo $A | sed 's/ABCDE//g' | sed 's/,,/,/g' | sed 's/vmfull=",/vmfull="/g' | sed 's/,"$/"/g'
-vmfulltype=vstor -vmbackuptype=fullvm -asnodename=NODE1 -MODE=IFIncremental -domain.vmfull="AAAAA,BBBBB,CCCCC"
```

Que dá o retorno desejado. Como pode ver, eu também juntei os comandos de suas duas questões.

Novamente, esse tipo de substituição sempre vai presumir algumas coisas do texto que se não forem verdade o comando não irá funcionar. Ele presume por exemplo que o argumento `vmfull` é o último da lista, ou que não existe nenhum caso de "vírgula dupla". Pode-se pensar em uma regex mais complexa, porém não acredito ser a melhor abordagem nesse caso.